# R programming - Read row values from one file and use as column names for another file

Tags: r

I have two text files. First file has single column with 200 rows and each row has unique value. Second file has 200 columns with `header=FALSE` and 3000 rows. I have to use row values of first file to give column name of second file.

First file rows are like:

```
[1] a
[2] b
...
...
[200] abc
```

Second file columns are like:

```
v1 v2 v3 ... ... v200
```

Now I have to replace `v1` by `'a'`. I tried multiple ways but could not solve it. Looking for some help.

---

I worked on this problem and found the solution as following.

Read the txt files.

```
df1<- read.table("file_1.txt", header=FALSE)

df2<- read.table("file_2.txt", header=FALSE)
```

Count the number of rows and use those to run the for loop so that row strings can be used to name the column names.

```
count <- nrow(df1)

for (i in 1:count){

names(df2)[i]<- toString(df1[i, 2])

}
```

---

Thanks a lot to community for providing possible solutions.

Comment: Did you try `names(df1) <- as.character(t(df2))`? What are the classes of your datasets? can you post `str(df1)` and `str(df2)` here?

Comment: Just tell us the classes of your "files" using `class()` or `str()`. Also please specify in the original post what have you tried exactly

Comment: Thanks a lot David. Your solution sparked me to think on my problem from different perspective and I arrived at logical solution for my problem.

Comment: Can't you just do `names(df2) <- as.character(df1[, 2])` without the `for` loop?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you have a a vector `A` that has 200 names in it and a data frame `B` that has 200 columns. And you want the 200 values from `A` to be used as column names for `B`.

Well, if the values in `A` are all legal (i.e. syntactically correct) column names, then this is as simple as:

`colnames(B) <- A`

Comment: Thanks a lot for possible solution. I tried your solution but it could not work.

Comment: +1 this is simple and is correct and it should work as per what ever you have asked, please try this : `df1 <- data.frame(x=LETTERS[1:10],y=seq(1:10));
df3 <- data.frame(matrix(1:100,10,10));
colnames(df3) <- df1[,1]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean. But, let's say you have a character vector then you can use the colnames function to use the character strings in this vector as column names for your second file. For example:

```
letters.red<-letters[1:10] # character vector

x<-1:100
dim(x)=c(10,10)
colnames(x)<-letters.red
```

I hope this helps. If not, maybe you could provide some data to show what you want exactly exactly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for possible solution. I tried but could not work.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have to *additionally* persist the data-frame B with the new column names (obtained from vector A), both the tasks can be done in one go:

```
write.table(B, file="a.csv", sep=",", row.names = FALSE, col.names = A)
```

However the answer by **tophcito** is the best.

Regards,

Sayan

Comment: Thanks a lot Sayan. I tried your solution but it could not work.

Comment: `B <- read.table(file = "people.csv", sep = ",")`
`A <- c("Name", "Location", "Gender")`
`write.table(B, file="a.csv", sep=",", row.names = FALSE, col.names = A)`
**As you can see, the write() function call is the same as mentioned in the earlier post.**

Answer (score 0):

If the names file is **file_1.txt** and **file_2.txt** is the 200 columns file:

```
df2<- read.table("file_2.txt", header=FALSE)
colnames(df2) <- scan("file_1.txt",what=character())
```